# How to filter rows that fall within 1st and 3rd quartile of a particular column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a data frame in python How can I filter all the rows that have value for a particular column , say val, which fall within 1st and 3rd quartile.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I saw that but still not able to figure out.

Comment: Show us your code so far, even if it isn't fully working.

Comment: I have a dataframe with a column named 'educationnum'. I want to select all rows that fall within 1st and 3rd quartile of 'educationnum'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
low, high = df.B.quantile([0.25,0.75])
df.query('{low}<B<{high}'.format(low=low,high=high))
```

Comment: got this error:
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas version is 0.13.1

Comment: there was version problem, now got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's create some random data with 100 rows and three columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
```

Now let's use `loc` to filter out all data in column `B` above and below its top and bottom quartile (retaining the middle).

```
lower_quantile, upper_quantile = df.B.quantile([.25, .75])

>>> df.loc[(df.B > lower_quantile) & (df.B < upper_quantile)].head()
           A         B         C
0   1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
2   0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3   0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4   0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
10  0.154947  0.378163 -0.887786
```

Comment: Got this error:
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.Series.between()` and unpacking the `quantile` values produced by `df.A.quantile([lower, upper])`, you can filter your `DataFrame`, here illustrated using sample data ranging 0-100:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.randint(0, 100, 10), 'B': np.arange(10)})

    A  B
0   4  0
1  21  1
2  96  2
3  50  3
4  82  4
5  24  5
6  93  6
7  16  7
8  14  8
9  40  9

df[df.A.between(*df.A.quantile([0.25, 0.75]).tolist())]


    A  B
1  21  1
3  50  3
5  24  5
9  40  9
```

On performance: `.query()` slows things down 2x:

```
df = DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000), 'B': np.arange(1000)})

def query(df):
    low, high = df.B.quantile([0.25,0.75])
    df.query('{low}<B<{high}'.format(low=low,high=high))

%timeit query(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop

def between(df):
    df[df.A.between(*df.A.quantile([0.25, 0.75]).tolist())]

%timeit between(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 995 µs per loop
```

@Alexander's solution performs identical to the one using `.between()`.

Comment: fyi, `between` could be heading for deprecation in 0.18.1.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: I get this error:

unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: Can you show the stack trace to see the source of the error? And ideally also show some of your data or the output of `df.info()`.

Comment: TypeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-d9ce14b24dbe> in <module>()
----> 1 df2=d[d.educationnum.between(*d.educationnum.quantile([0.25, 0.75]).tolist())]

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in quantile(self, q)
   1322         if len(valid_values) == 0:
   1323             return pa.NA
-> 1324         result = _quantile(valid_values, q * 100)
   1325         if result.dtype == _TD_DTYPE:
   1326             from pandas.tseries.timedeltas import to_timedelta
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: data consists  of 15 attributes and around 3000 rows

Comment: Do you have a numeric datatype in `educationnum`? What's the `dtype` indicated by `df.info()` for that column? There is `df.educationnum = df.educationnum.astype(float)` or  `df.educationnum = df.educationnum.to_numeric()` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: Are these maybe typos where it says d[d.educ..] instead of perhaps df[df.edu..]?

Comment: no its d only. Maybe there are missing values in that column. I will try to solve tat problem in case it exists.